# MySQL Exclude results from JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
locations
---------------------
| id    INT, PK, AI |
| x     INT         |
| y     INT         |
---------------------

signals
---------------------
| id    INT, PK, AI |
| location_id INT   |
| mac         INT   |
| strength    INT   |
---------------------
```

One location can (will) have up to maximum of 4 signals. Where location is X,Y point on an image and signal is Access Point in range of X,Y and it's signal strength.

Anyhow I have a method to which I provide a `List` of up to 4 MAC addresses and I need to find all `locations` that contain those 4 addresses.

Right now I'm doing this programmatically by:
1. Take top signal strength at `X,Y` and it's mac addresses
2. `SELECT * FROM signals WHERE mac = ScanResult.BSSID`
3. Create array of ID's from returned `signals.location_id`
4. In bulk select all locations if their ID is in the array along with all signals related to those locations
5. Complex loop in loop creates an array containing all locations that have in their relationship all the 4 mac addresses that I provided in the `List` and delete others.

This is incredibly messy and has redundant queries but since I'm not very good with SQL it was a patch that sort of worked.

Now I was wondering if I can do this using SQL alone and return `locations` that contain those 4 mac addresses.

I have:

```
SELECT locations.*, signals.* FROM locations INNER JOIN signals ON locations.id = signals.location_id;
```

I would be less confused if I only had to exclude locations where a relation would be 1:1 but here each locations has up to 4 signals. Is there a way I could provide an "array" to the query and say from that `JOIN` remove all `locations` that do not contain this number of mac addresses and these mac addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andomar's solution is correct based on the sample query.  However, the data structure differs from the query, and the query doesn't really make sense.  I think this is all that is necessary:

```
SELECT s.location_id
FROM signals s
WHERE s.MAC in (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY s.location_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.MAC) = 4;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `having` clause to ensure a location has all four MAC addresses:

```
SELECT  l.id
,       l.x
,       l.y
FROM    locations l
JOIN    signals s
ON      s.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE   s.MAC in (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY
        l.id
,       l.x
,       l.y
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT s.MAC) = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I could provide an "array" to the query

Yes, there is an [operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) for this. You can even provide another query as parameter

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE id IN (SELECT location_id FROM signals WHERE mac = ScanResult.level);
```

- you can also use `NOT IN` to exclude elements which are contained in the list

Comment: This would return any location that has any of the MAC addresses. The OP wants locations that have ALL of the provided MAC addresses.